# How can I make this JS code more functional using setTimeout and promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, functional-programming

I'm trying to learn how to code using more functions and less loops and just in a more functional way. I want to implement a time out between calling connectBing. I was wondering if it's possible not to use the i variable and still get a 1 second time out between iterations. My code currently works but I'm looking for other ways to write it without using i.

This is my code:

```
// MAIN
getAllPosts().then((posts) => {
    posts
        .forEach( (post, i) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                connectBing(anchorText,console.log).then()
            } ,i * 1000)
        })

// CONNECT TO BING WITH KW AND DO SOMETHING
function connectBing(anchorText,doSomethingWithBing) {
    var deferred = q.defer();                                                                   
    request('https://www.cnn.com/search?q=' + anchorText, function (error, response, body) {    
        error ? console.log('error:', error) :                                                    
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);                              
        (doSomethingWithBing) ? doSomethingWithBing(body) : "You didn't give connectBing anything to do!"       
    })
    return deferred.promise                 
}
```

Comment: The way you are currently writing it you dont get a 1 second timeout between iterations you get an i second timeout.... not sure what you're asking for...

Comment: what are you trying to do ? Here, if you had 1k queries, that d spawn 1k query over 1k seconds. In my understanding you are looking for a concurrent model to not spam the server and keep processing things with higher rate possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an array of async functions and chain each to run after the other. I will use native promises to demonstrate, and you can map it to the library you are using.

First create a function which takes in an array of async fucntions. It will chain one after the other, returning the last:

```
function chainAsyncFns(fns) {
    // Ensure we have at least one promise to return

    let promise = Promise.resolve();

    fns.forEach(fn => promise = promise.then(fn));

    return promise;
}
```

Then for each post, create an async function which will call `connectBing` and then wait for a timeout:

```
function connectBing() {
    // Pretend we are connecting to a data source

    return Promise.resolve();
}

function delay(ms) {
    // Return a promise that resolves when the timeout is up

    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

let fns = posts.map(post => () => {
    return connectBing()
        .then(() => delay(1000))
        .catch(() => console.log('error'));
});
```

Chain the functions to run one after the other:

```
chainAsyncFns(fns).then(() => console.log('done'));
```

Comment: what happens if an error swpan in the middle of the processing ?

Comment: @mh-cbon Good question, I wasn't sure how far to take this example. I updated my example to catch errors when creating the async functions.